# Is there a way to make my Android app run some custom code upon installation?

Tags: android, installation

I have some ideas about running some anti-piracy measures for my app so I wondered if I could do this to sign the application on install. Running the code on first launch is no good, because someone could still copy out the apk without running it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to run code on install on Android unfortunately, only run on first launch.

If you're interested in anti-piracy measures you'll find [this post on the Android Developers blog about securing the Android License Verification Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/securing-android-lvl-applications.html) interesting, if you haven't read it already.

Comment: I heard reports that someone quite easily hacked the one that Google provided as standard so I was considering a second layer. I'll give that a read, cheers :)