# Android - Installing apk from SD cord

Tags: android

I'm distributing my android application (apk) along with some encrypted audio files in SD card. After installing the apk on the android phone, i want the apk to be deleted automatically. Actually I dont want the apk to be copied by others.
Is there any solution such that apk cant be installed or copied by others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By distributing it on an SD card you're making it **very** easy for people to copy. What's to stop them from just copying the card? Even if you come up with a way to prevent this from being done on Android, they could just insert the card into any other type of computer.

Comment: You are right. I'm trying to find a solution to avoid using my app even after copying from the SD card/computer.

Comment: Automatically, deleting from the card or from the phone?
Deleting from the card is easy. File todelete = new File("/mnt/sdcard/myApp.apk); todelete.delete(); along with the permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
Of course this doesn't stop people from making a backup of the card before putting it in their phone.

Comment: Where should this code be put so that immediately after installation the apk must be deleted from the SD card.

Comment: The best you can do is make the code run the first time the app is run. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700974/is-there-a-way-to-make-my-android-app-run-some-custom-code-upon-installation You'd do this with code in the onCreate method of the Application class. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Answer (score 0):

> i want the apk to be deleted automatically

Automatic deleting no , you can prompt the user for for that at max.

I do not why you want to do this but you can definitely make your app inactive, implement :

x times run policy or implement run for x days only depending on your need but then again when they reinstall the app will work.

So add an online activation module and keep phone details to avoid reactivation